# disambiguate tokens without using tokenizer state

Tags: java, parsing, tokenize, javacc

I cannot get JavaCC to properly disambiguate tokens by their place in a grammar. I have the following JJTree file (I'll call it `bug.jjt`):

```
options
{
  LOOKAHEAD = 3;
  CHOICE_AMBIGUITY_CHECK = 2;
  OTHER_AMBIGUITY_CHECK = 1;
  SANITY_CHECK = true;
  FORCE_LA_CHECK = true;
}
PARSER_BEGIN(MyParser)
import java.util.*;
public class MyParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        MyParser parser = new MyParser(new java.io.StringReader(args[0]));
        SimpleNode root = parser.production();
        root.dump("");
    }
}
PARSER_END(MyParser)

SKIP:
{
    " "
}

TOKEN:
{
     <STATE:  ("state")>
     |<PROD_NAME: (["a"-"z"])+ >
}


SimpleNode production():
{}
{
    (
        <PROD_NAME>
        <STATE>
        <EOF>
    )
    {return jjtThis;}
}
```

Generate the parser code with the following:

```
java -cp C:\path\to\javacc.jar jjtree bug.jjt
java -cp C:\path\to\javacc.jar javacc bug.jj
```

Now after compiling this, you can give run MyParser from the command line with a string to parse as the argument. It prints `production` if successful and spews an error if it fails.

I tried two simple inputs: `foo state` and `state state`. The first one parses, but the second one does not, since both `state` strings are tokenized as `<STATE>`. As I set `LOOKAHEAD` to 3, I expected it to use the grammar and see that one string `state` must be `<STATE>` and the other must be `<PROD_NAME`. However, no such luck. I have tried changing the various lookahead parameters to no avail. I am also not able to use tokenizer states (where you define different tokens allowable in different states), as this example is part of a more complicated system that will probably have a lot of these types of ambiguities.

Can anyone tell me how to make JavaCC properly disambiguate these tokens, without using tokenizer states?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the [FAQ](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/) under question 4.19.

There are three strategies outlined there

**Putting choices in the grammar.** See Bart Kiers's answer.

**Using semantic look ahead.**  For this approach you get rid of the production defining `STATE` and write your grammar like this

```
void SimpleNode production():
{}
{
    (
        <PROD_NAME>
        ( LOOKAHEAD({getToken(1).kind == PROD_NAME && getToken(1).image.equals("state")})
         <PROD_NAME>
         ...
        |
         ...other choices...
        )
    )
    {return jjtThis;}
}
```

If there are no other choices, then

```
void SimpleNode production():
{}
{
    (
        <PROD_NAME>
        ( LOOKAHEAD({getToken(1).kind == PROD_NAME && getToken(1).image.equals("state")})
         <PROD_NAME>
         ...
        |
         { int[][] expTokSeqs = new int[][] { new int[] {STATE } } ;
           throw new ParseException(token, expTokSeqs, tokenImage) ; }
        )
    )
    {return jjtThis;}
}
```

But, in this case, you need a production for `STATE`, as it is mentioned in the initialization of `expTokSeqs`. So you need a production.

```
< DUMMY > TOKEN : { < STATE : "state" > }
```

where `DUMMY` is a state that is never gone to.

**Using lexical states.**  The title of the OP's question suggests he doesn't want to do this, but not why.  It can be done if the state switching can be contained in the token manager.  Suppose a file is a sequence of productions and each of production look like this.

```
name state : "a" | "b" name ;
```

That is it starts with a name, then the keyword "state" a colon, some tokens and finally a semicolon. (I'm just making this up as I have no idea what sort of language the OP is trying to parse.)  Then you can use three lexical states DEFAULT, S0, and S1.

- In the DEFAULT any sequence of letters (including "state") is a PROD_NAME. In DEFAULT, recognizing  a PROD_NAME switches the state to S0.
- In S0 any sequence of letters except "state" is a PROD_NAME and "state" is a STATE. In S0, recognizing a STATE token causes the tokenizer to switch to state S1.
- In S1 any any sequence of letters (including "state") is a PROD_NAME. In S1, recognizing a SEMICOLON switches the state to DEFAULT.

So our example is tokenized like this

```
name  state  : "a" | "b" name ;
|__||______||_________________||_________
DEF-   S0             S1                    DEFAULT
AULT
```

The productions are written like this

```
<*> SKIP: { " " }

<S0> TOKEN: { <STATE: "state"> : S1 }

<DEFAULT> TOKEN:{ <PROD_NAME: (["a"-"z"])+ >  : S0 }
<S0,S1> TOKEN:{ <PROD_NAME: (["a"-"z"])+ >  }

<S1> TOKEN: { <SEMICOLON : ";" > : DEFAULT
<S0, DEFAULT> TOKEN : { <SEMICOLON : ";" > }

<*> TOKEN {
     COLON : ":"
|    ...etc...
}
```

It is possible for the parser to send state switching commands back to the tokenizer, but it is tricky to get it right and fragile.  Se  question 3.12 of the FAQ.

Comment: Ah, the lookahead keyword makes more sense. Why would I need to throw an error if the lookahead fails and there aren't any other options? Shouldn't the parser take care of what happens when lookahead doesn't find anything?

Comment: You are right. But, when semantic lookahead is used where there is no choice, the error message is not very helpful to the user.  The way I suggested gives a better error message.  I'll edit the answer to improve the error message further by adding line and column numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The `LOOKAHEAD` option only applies to the parser (production rules). The tokenizer is not affected by this: it will produce tokens without worrying what a production rule is trying to match. The input `"state"` will always be tokenized as a `STATE`, even if the parser is trying to match a `PROD_NAME`.

You could do something like this (untested, pseudo-ish grammar code ahead!):

```
SimpleNode production():
{}
{
    (
        prod_name_or_state()
        <STATE>
        <EOF>
    )
    {return jjtThis;}
}

SimpleNode prod_name_or_state():
{}
{
    (   
        <PROD_NAME>
    |   <STATE>
    )
    {return jjtThis;}
}
```

which would match both `"foo state"` and `"state state"`.

Or the equivalent, but more compact:

```
SimpleNode production():
{}
{
    (
        ( <PROD_NAME> | <STATE> )
        <STATE>
        <EOF>
    )
    {return jjtThis;}
}
```

Comment: Right, but <PROD_NAME> <PROD_NAME> is not contained in the original grammar.

Comment: @laune, the rules I posted do not allow for `<PROD_NAME> <PROD_NAME>`. It matches `<PROD_NAME> <STATE>` and `<STATE> <STATE>`.

Comment: Sorry, but then `<STATE> <STATE>` isn't in the original grammar.

Comment: @laune, that is correct, but the OP does want to parse the input `"state state"`, as he indicated. It doesn't matter that this gets parsed as `<STATE> <STATE>`: in further handling of the AST, the token that matched `prod_name_or_state()` will just need to be treated as if it were a `<PROD_NAME>`.

Comment: Which means that all semantic operations have to be duplicated. I assume from OP's Q, that this would not be the only case of a "keyword" being permitted as an identifier, so this isn't a very pleasing option. - Technically, you are correct, but will it result in a "good" solution - which we can't judge without knowing the overall picture?

Comment: Well, this is generally the way such problems (keywords can be identifiers) are solved using parser generators that have a strict separation between parsing and tokenizing. One may argue that adding all keywords in such a separate rule (like `prod_name_or_state`) is cumbersome, but it's a far better option than making the tokenizer context sensitive by changing states (all IMO, of course :)).

Comment: Yes, I needed it to come out `PROD_NAME STATE`, meaning that I wanted the tokenization to be done differently, which is apparently not possible.

Comment: Why do you care how the tokenization comes out?  The .jjt file defines a partial function from sequences of characters to trees, as long as you describe the right function, the way to do it is of little consequence.  If you really want the tokenization to come out the way you say, then lexical states are your only option.

Answer (score 1):

Lookahead does not concern the lexer while it composes characters to tokens. It is used by the parser when it matches non-terminals as composed from terminals (tokens).

If you define "state" to result in a token STATE, well, then that's what it is.

I agree with you, that tokenizer states aren't a good solution for permitting keywords to be used as identifiers. Is this really necessary? There's a good reason for HLL's not to permit this.

OTOH, if you can rewrite your grammar using just `<PROD_NAME>`s you might postpone the recognitions of the keywords during semantic analysis.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. I didn't realize that tokenization and parsing were separated so sharply, which seems like a handicap but probably helps performance, right? So the answer is to use the more general token `<PROD_NAME>` and then validate the value by hand when it should specifically be `<STATE>`.

Comment: Sorry, do you happen to know how to do that? I need a `reject` method or something. `if(!t.image.equals("state"){reject parse here}`.

Comment: I think that the answer referring you to FAQ 4.19 should help you over all difficulties.